# zip files before copying from Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, copying, zip

20,000 small files takes forever to copy. Is there an easy way to zip files on a Windows Server before copying to a client desktop? It must be simple enough for a novice user to do it from the client computer.

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the server? RDP? Just file access?

Comment: Ctrl+A -> Right Click -> Send to Compressed (zipped) folder. Moreover, you can write a powershell script for doing that.

Comment: `Is there an easy way to zip files on a Windows Server before copying to a client desktop?` - Yes, there is.

Comment: RalfFriedl, the users only have SMB file access to the server.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I could, Strepsils. However, turning that PS script into a client side app for users to run remotely, is beyond me. Send to compressed folder context menu option doesn't seem to do anything.